# Wait for user kill signal in a swift command line program

Tags: swift, async-await, screen-recording, screencapturekit

I am new to swift. I am trying to build a command line wrapper around ScreenCaptureKit. The idea is that when i run the command, it starts capturing the main screen and then stops the capturing when user sends the kill signal to the command (ctrl+c). The program also writes the captured video to a file.

I could not figure out how to wait for user's input (the kill signal) while the video stream is being captured.

```swift
struct ScreenCaptureKitCLI: AsyncParsableCommand {
    mutating func run() async throws {
        // Create a screen recording
        do {
            // Check for screen recording permission, make sure your terminal has screen recording permission
            guard CGPreflightScreenCaptureAccess() else {
                throw RecordingError("No screen capture permission")
            }
            
            let url = URL(filePath: FileManager.default.currentDirectoryPath).appending(path: "recording \(Date()).mov")
            //    let cropRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 960, height: 540)
            let screenRecorder = try await ScreenRecorder(url: url, displayID: CGMainDisplayID(), cropRect: nil)
            print("Starting screen recording of main display")
            try await screenRecorder.start()
            // This await only waits for the recording to start. After that ScreenCaptureKit keeps sending the frames to the stream we provide it.
            // TODO: Need some way to keep the program running until the user sends a kill signal
        } catch {
            print("Error during recording:", error)
        }
        
    }
}
```

I am using the ArgumentParser library for building the CLI program.

Here's the link to what i have written so far - https://github.com/mukeshsoni/screencapturekit-cli/blob/main/Sources/screencapturekit-cli/ScreenCaptureKitCli.swift

Any help or pointers would be really appreciated.

I tried using `Dispatch` but was not able to use it inside an async function. None of the solutions from the 'Trapping signals in a swift command line application' questions worked inside the `mutating func run() async throws {` needed to implement `AsyncParsableCommand` protocol.